# How do I translate the >>> operator in JavaScript to VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, bit-shift

I am doing code conversion from JavaScript to [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET). I am stuck with the >>> operation.

See the sample code and my attempt below:

JavaScript:

```
function test(a, b) {
    return (a << b) | (a >>> (32 - b))
}
```

My attempt in VB.NET:

```
Private Function test(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
    Return ((a << b) Or (CUShort(a) >> (32 - b)))
End Function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use CUInt instead of CUShort.

CUShort gives an UShort which is only 16-bit in size. In JavaScript all bit operations are done in 32-bit, so `a` should be converted to a 32-bit unsigned type as well — which is UInteger.

Comment: i have tried CUInt, CUShort and CULng but i get errors overflow errors